# Selenium actions not allowed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem when automating a web application.

If I open the web application in a normal browser, I am able to key in the username and password and login.

But when I automate this through Selenium, the application is not logging in. It shows an hour glass when I click on login, but does not login. I saw in the console, no errors or information was present.

Comment: what do mean by Not Allowed ? are you really doing configuration in proper or right way. There is no code and no exception error stack trace which supports to your issue.

Comment: All configurations are correct. No errors at all. Just that when i open the browser manually, launch the application, enter the credentials and click on login... it logs in... but when i do this through selenium it does not login. It clicks on login button but the login doesn’t happen. Is the application blocking the automated actions as part of security?

Comment: no i don't think such.
Selenium is meant to be design for user specific commands executions.
Please verify that you are actually clicking on <button> tag.
OR You might be getting forgotten something about user interactions.
Please look carefully what you do in manually. Do exact same while automation.
Small small events like key press, key down, key up, focus element matters too.

Comment: use wait command thread.sleep(2000) @prakash

Answer (score 1):

try putting some wait() will solve your issue.
Sometimes javascript not getting loaded properly before any action going to happen.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.id("ID_OF_ELEMENT"))));
```

try Actions class to perform waited click on element,

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Your ID Here"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement);
builder.perform();
```

if not worked try this with javascript executor also does same thing,

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

Comment: Nothing is working. In fact in the browser which is opened and controlled by Selenium, even if I press the login button manually, it is not logging in.... It's very strange and coming across for the first time.